# How to filter a query using the max(date) value

Tags: django, datetime, aggregate

I have this model:

```
class LogBook_audit(models.Model):
    id             = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    logbook        = models.ForeignKey(LogBook, verbose_name='Logbook Control No.')
    username       = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True,  verbose_name='Username')
    status         = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=40, choices=STATUS_TYPE, default=u'CHECKING REQUIREMENTS', verbose_name='Status')
    log_in         = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda:datetime.now(), verbose_name='Work start')
```

I'm trying to create a queryset to find latest user who log_in for such specific logbook and status.

### view.py

```
undolink(request, pk):
    undo_rec     = LogBook.objects.get(pk=pk)
    latest_user  = LogBook_audit.objects.filter(logbook_id=pk, status=undo_rec.status).aggregate(Max('log_in'))
...
```

But latest_user is giving me a latest log_in format. I was thinking I can used `latest_user.username` but failed. Is there a way to find that username? Any guide is really appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`latest()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest) instead:

```
latest_log = LogBook_audit.objects.filter(logbook_id=pk, status=undo_rec.status).latest('log_in')
```

then you can access user through `latest_log.user`.

Comment: I never thought there is such method in queryset. The result gave me one latest record with minimal coding than the first thing I used given by [Joe Holloway](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1296986/2074141).

Comment: That answer is from august 2009. A lot in Django has changed since then.

Comment: Like `latest()` is their any function like `oldest()`?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare You can use [earliest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#earliest)

Answer (score 1):

You want to get a queryset result, so you should use `annotate()`:

```
latest_user = (LogBook_audit.objects
               .filter(logbook_id=pk, status=undo_rec.status)
               .annotate(max_log_in=Max('log_in')))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The results gave me 3 records which are equivalent to logbook_id and status. I still need to find the max log_in among the 3. `print latest_user[0],max_log_in`, `print latest_user[1].max_log_in`, `print latest_user[2].max_log_in`.